# How to exit from a Describe upon a condition(having multiple It's) and proceed to next describe using Protractor Jasmine

Tags: javascript, protractor, jasmine-node

I have multiple describes and each describe is an E2E test which contains multiple It blocks which are dependent on each other. When I trigger batch execution(Considering 5 test describes/specs) using protractor.config.js, it read the required Describe files and start the batch execution sequentially. Considering each describe has 5 It blocks. When 2nd It block is failed, I want to exit from current describe without executing 3 to 5 it blocks and start the next Describe test.  I tried to use process.exit which terminates the entire batch execution. We can manage flag condition for each it block and handle the case and it is a tedious process. Is there any direct way we can exit from current spec and jump to next spec execution?

Your Suggestions will be highly appreciated...